# Navigation bar disappear when navigate from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to navigate to a specific view controller when user click on notification tray.Therefore I need to redirect them from AppDelegate class:

**Here is the code in AppDelegate :**

```
if let myVc = UIStoryboard(name : "Main",bundle : nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController")
    as? MyViewController {

         myVc.postId = Int(postId)
         if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController /* as? UINavigationController */{
          navigationController.show(myVc, sender: Any?.self)
         }
  }
```

By using this code,when I click on the notification tray,I can redirect to my MyViewController,but the problem is the navigation bar is gone,so the app is just stuck over there.

**I tried using this as well,but by the code below,it cant redirect to myPostVc:**

```
if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController  as? UINavigationController {
  navigationController.pushViewController(myVc, animated: true)
}
```

**So my question is:**

How to navigate to a specific view controller from AppDelegate with Navigation bar appear on destination view controller?

Comment: so where should I push the view controller when I get data from the notification??

Comment: are you sure that the current view controller is embeded inside a navigation controller or you don't use it

Comment: the current view controller is inside tabbarcontroller

Comment: the tabbar controller is the main entrance of my app..once launch it will launch the tabbar controller 1st

Comment: thats why I have no idea how to do in this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the tabBar inside a navigation Controller (in code as the embed is grayed when you select a tabbar and want to embed it inside a naigation controller in storyboard) and use this to push the VC

```
 if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController  as? UINavigationController {
    navigationController.pushViewController(myVc, animated: true)
 }
```

OR you can do this

```
if let cu = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
 {         
       let nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController()

        self.window?.rootViewController = nav

        let str = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let rr = str.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idOFPushedVC") 

         nav.setViewControllers([cu,rr], animated: true)

  }
```